# multiple buffered input streams from single file while writing to that file?

Tags: c, linux, unix, fopen

I'm tackling a sorting problem that involves sorting a file that is larger than main memory.  The first phase generates an intermediate file whose size is the identical to the original input file but that contains some number of locally sorted sub-sections.

The second phase merges these sub-sections back into a single sorted list.

Instead of creating a third file to contain the single sorted list I would like to overwrite the intermediate file that I'm reading from *as I'm reading from it*.

Additionally, I'd like to maintain separate read buffers for each input stream (each of which is reading from some offset into the intermediate file).

I know I can use fopen() and fseek() to create multiple buffered read-only input streams.  However, the contract for fopen() stipulates that calling it on a file in "w" mode sets the file's size to zero if it already exists.  I need it to not alter the file's size since I'm still reading from it in multiple places.

Is there a straightforward way to accomplish this using fopen() & fseek()?  Or am I going to need to use open() and manage my own read/write buffering?

Comment: Overwriting the intermediate file will be very complicated. Consider the case where you have input subsections in order `faebdc`, without any overlap in contents. Using a temporary file for each sub-section will usually be faster due to fewer I/O and quite linear access patterns. Using `mmap()` for the source data is usually even better, and does not need any extra temporary files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first suggest that you get your program to work by writing to a third file.  Then if conditions require you to update a file in place then create a copy of your "simple" program that works and modify it.

This way, when you test your new program you will be able to compare it to prior results that work.  that is, eventually both the simple and new programs should produce the same sorted file.

Comment: @ash it questions the question.  If the first step is taken the analyst might realize the more difficult second step is **not** necessary.

Answer (score 2):

You can just open the file in `r+` mode, which means it is open for both reading and writing, and doesn't truncate the file.

Answer (score 0):

Read [fopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopen.3.html) man page. You probably want the `"r+"` mode.

Alternatively, consider using instead the [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) and [madvise(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/madvise.2.html) syscalls (without any `<stdio.h>` functions)